# Bug: Form submission adding items to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am very new to HTML and Javascript so I'm sure this is something pretty basic that I have wrong. However, I have a very basic single page website set up that gets data from a Firebase RTDB to display certain info, and to be able to publish data to the database from a form submission. When the webpage loads I populate a dropdown list with headers from some Json data received from the database, this works completely fine and populates it as it should.
[image: what the dropdown list looks like at the start]
However, when I select an item from the dropdown, then publish data to the database, the dropdown repopulates self again so all the  items in the list are added again.
[image: Here it is doubled]
This seems to occur only sometimes, not every time and I'm having a hard time gettting the bug to activate consistently, sometimes it adds items every time you send data and other times only some times.

Heres some of my HTML:

```
</head>
<body  onload="populateDropdown()">
    
    <h1 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 60px;
                text-shadow: 0cqmax;
                color: coral;"
    >SunSync</h1>
    <form action="#">       
        <label for="sel">Choose a Dispenser</label>
        <select id="sel">
            <option value="">Dispensers </option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Choose" onclick="displayData(document.getElementById('sel'))" />
    </form>   
   <div id="deviceInfo" style="display: none;">
    <P>Dispenser: <span id="reading-dispenserName"></span></P>
    <P>Dispenser Location: <span id="reading-cityName"></span></P>
    <p>Uv Index: <span id="reading-uvindex"></span></p>
    <p>Weather: <span id="reading-weather"></span></p>
    <p>Danger: <span id="reading-category"></span></p>
    <p>Time Above 3: <span id="reading-timeabove"></span></p>
    
    <form id="messageToSend" action="#">
        <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id='message' name="message"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sendMessage(document.getElementById('message').value)">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And heres some of my Javascript functions:

```
function populateDropdown(){
  //This gets the dispenser list 
  //document.getElementById("sel").options.length=0;
  let i = 0;
  databaseCityList.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    cityList = snapshot.val();
    console.log(cityList);
    var items = [];
    items = cityList;
    
    const obj = JSON.stringify(cityList);
    const list = JSON.parse(obj);
    console.log(list);

    var cityListOfLists = [];

  //This sorts the data into an array for sorting
  var sel = document.getElementById('sel')
  for(items in list){
      
      console.log(items);
      cityListOfLists.push(items);
            i++;
            console.log(i);
    }

    console.log(cityListOfLists);

    //This cycles through the list and appends the various dispenser names into the dropdown list
    let p = 0;
    for (items in cityListOfLists){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = cityListOfLists[p];
        opt.value = cityListOfLists[p];
        sel.appendChild(opt);
        console.log(cityListOfLists[p]);
        p++;

    }
    //Reset variables otherwise dropwdown grows after message send? --didnt work - worked once?
    i = 0;
    p = 0;
  //Error handling
    document.getElementById("reading-citylist").innerHTML = list.Victoria;
  }, (errorObject) => {
    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
  }); 

}

function sendMessage(){
  //This sends a message to the desired path -- Sending a message doubles the dropdown?
    var device1 = document.getElementById("sel").value;
    
    var messagePath = "/Dispensers/"
    messagePath += device1;
    messagePath += "/message/";

  database.ref(messagePath).set(document.getElementById('message').value, function(error) {
  if (error) {
      // The write failed...
      console.log("Failed with error: " + error)
  } else {
      // The write was successful...
      console.log("success")
      console.log(document.getElementById('message').value)
  }
})}
```

So far I've adjusted everything that I could think,like adding some code to the top of my populateDropdown function to completely erase my dropdown items but this bug still occurs. Like I said I'm very new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the principle of submitting in a form is to send information to a server by asking it to process this information by the page referenced in the action property. In, your case this is the same page which does not seem to have any mechanism to handle this reception when it reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Once you´ve received the data to fill the dropdown, you should remove the listener set with the on() method calling the off() method.

Here is the documentation for removing listeners:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners